# Mautic installation via Laravel sub-domain throws error

Tags: laravel-8, mautic

I receive this error while trying to install mautic via laravel subdomain routing.

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError 
Class Symfony\Component\Validator\Util\LegacyTranslatorProxy cannot implement previously implemented interface Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface
```